# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker when saving to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I'm trying to save my objects to my local database. We are using Microsoft Entity Framework and Ninject. Currently when I try to save my object I get the *'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'* error. We are able to get data from the database currently, it is saving data that is causing problems.

The error is given the moment the savetickets function is called, Visual studio displays the error in the repository at context.Tickets.add(ticket). I have tried passing a single object instead of a list and saving that, this has however caused the same error.

We apply the same principle of creating repositories in other controllers as well for getting data from the database before we get to this part of the code where I'm trying to save tickets.

We have added a Ninject binding

```
kernel.Bind<ITicketRepository>().To<TicketRepository>();
```

Our EFDBContext looks like this

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    // Other Entities
    public EFDbContext() : base("EFDbContext"){

    }
}
```

The interface for the ticketrepository looks like this

```
public interface ITicketRepository
{
    // Other functions
    void SaveTickets(List<Ticket> tickets);
}
```

The repository implementing this interface looks like this

```
public class TicketRepository : ITicketRepository
{
    private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
    // Other functions
    public void SaveTickets(List<Ticket> tickets)
    {
        foreach (var item in tickets)
        {
            context.Tickets.Add(item);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The moment all of this is called is in my printtickets function. This is the only time the ticketrepository is created and called for in the code.

```
public class ReservationController : Controller
{
    // Other repositories
    private ITicketRepository ticketRepository;

    public ReservationController(IMovieOverviewRepository movieRepository, IShowRepository showRepository, ITicketRepository ticketRepository)
    {
        // Other repositories
        this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
    }

    // Other code

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult PrintTickets()
    {
        List<Ticket> tickets = (List<Ticket>)TempData["TicketList"];
        ticketRepository.SaveTickets(tickets);
        // Irrelevant stuff
    }
}
```

EDIT: Our full ninject configuration. NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Sprint123.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }        
    }
```

And NinjectDependencyResolver.cs

```
namespace Sprint123.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
        private void AddBindings()
        {
            kernel.Bind<IShowRepository>().To<ShowRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<ITicketRepository>().To<TicketRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<IMovieOverviewRepository>().To<MovieOverviewRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GertArnold We haven't defined a cycle or scope in our repositories. I've added our Ninject configuration in my original post.

Comment: So it's transient scope (the default), which means it can't be related to singleton context issues. Does `Ticket` have any nested objects (i.e. populated navigation properties) when it's added?

Comment: @GertArnold The Ticket does have nested objects, it contains a Movie object and a Show object, that are all filled within the Ticket object that I am trying to save and for which there are seperate repositories.

Comment: Then it's these objects that are attempted to attach multiple times. `Add(item)` also tries to add nested objects.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks for helping me out. Kind of annoying that the error is not more specific in mentioning that I was doing this.

Comment: If you use inProc session, I guess the problem comes from the TempData. You seem to be trying to save objects that have been loaded by a different DbContext in a preceding request. If possible (objects are serializable), try to use another SessionMode and see if it makes a difference.